# #each helper to populate a table

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'm fairly new to meteor and I'm trying to iterate over a cursor using #each to populate a table. Here's my code:

```
<template name="choral">
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 25px">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <form id="orderForm">
    <table class="table table-borderless table-dark">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Title:</th>
            <th>See the Music:</th>
            <th>Hear the Music:</th>
            <th>Format:</th>
            <th>Price (per copy):</th>
            <th>Quantity:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {{#each piece in pieces}}
        <tr>
            <td id="name">{{piece.name}}</td>
            <td id="pdf">PDF</td>
            <td id="audio">AUDIO</td>
            <td id="format">FORMAT</td>
            <td id="price">{{piece.score}}</td>
            <td id="qty"><input type ="number" name ="quantity" min="5"></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <td><button class="button" type ="submit">Add to Cart</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
  </table>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

my js.

```
Template.choral.helpers({
  pieces: function(){
    return choralm.find({});
  }
});
```

I'm outputting a blank row between the #each tag. I publish the collection server side and subscribe. I'm just not sure where to look. Any ideas?
My publishment and subscription:

```
Meteor.publish('choralList', function() {
  return choralm.find();
});

Template.choral.onCreated( function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('choralList');
});
```

Comment: . Maybe your collection is empty, or you did not check for the subscription to be ready. Could you please show the code where you subscribe?

Comment: I did a manual insert so I know the collection is populated.

Comment: 'Template.choral.onCreated( function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('choralList');
});'  and when I published i 'Meteor.publish('choralList', function() {
        return choralm.find();
    });'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you are subscribing to your data but you are not "telling" your template, that the subscription is finished and it should redraw.

Therefore your template immediately renders while the subscription is ongoing and thus uses the yet empty collection data.

In order to inform your template that data has been updated you can use it's internal `Tracker` and store the information in a reactive data-source (for my example I use `ReactiveDict` instead of `ReactiveVar`).

```js
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';

Template.choral.onCreated( function (){
  // inside onCreated, this refers to the
  // current template instance 
  const instance = this;

  // let's attach a ReactiveDict to the instance
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict();

  // use the internal Tracker
  instance.autorun(() => {
    // subscribe and store a flag, once ready
    const choralListSub = Meteor.subscribe('choralList');
    if (choralListSub.ready()) {
      instance.state.set('subscriptionComplete', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Next you add a helper, that returns the reactive value for `'subscriptionComplete'`:

```js
Template.choral.helpers({
  pieces(){
    return choralm.find({});
  },
  subscriptionComplete() {
    // we use 'state', our ReactiveDict,
    // which we added as prop in onCreated
    return Template.instance().state.get('subscriptionComplete');
  }
});
```

And finally we let our template draw the data, once our subscription is complete. Until the subscription is complete (note the `{{else}}` block), we display a message about the loading status:

```html
<template name="choral">
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 25px">
  {{#if subscriptionComplete}}
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <form id="orderForm">
    <table class="table table-borderless table-dark">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Title:</th>
            <th>See the Music:</th>
            <th>Hear the Music:</th>
            <th>Format:</th>
            <th>Price (per copy):</th>
            <th>Quantity:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {{#each piece in pieces}}
        <tr>
            <td id="name">{{piece.name}}</td>
            <td id="pdf">PDF</td>
            <td id="audio">AUDIO</td>
            <td id="format">FORMAT</td>
            <td id="price">{{piece.score}}</td>
            <td id="qty"><input type ="number" name ="quantity" min="5"></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <td><button class="button" type ="submit">Add to Cart</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
  </table>
  </form>
  </div>
  {{else}}
  <div>Loading template...</div>
  {{/if}}
</div>
</template>
```

### Related resources

**TemplateInstance.autorun**

http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun

https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html

**Reactive stores**

https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#stores

**Subscription readyness**

https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#readiness

**Helpers**

http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Built-in-Block-Helpers